# while loading page hide div display

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using given script for hide div when page load or refresh but while page load that time hidden div display,How to resolve this problem ?That means hidden div display while page or to take time to load page that time hidden div display after that hidden div

```html
<div id="display">
  <div class="w-section">
   <label style="margin-left: 285px;">Coupon Name</label>
  </div>  
  <div class="w-section" >
   <label style="margin-left: 285px;">Transaction Amount</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#display").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Please add full code with script

Comment: There is no element with id `display`.

Comment: can tell what you want to do, i mean more clearly.

Comment: Do you want to hide the element before the page load or hide the element after the page fully loaded

Answer (score 2):

it take time to load jQuery you can add `display:none` inline like

```
<div id="display" style="display:none">
    <div class="w-section">
        <label style="margin-left: 285px;">Coupon Name</label>
    </div>      
    <div class="w-section" >
        <label style="margin-left: 285px;">Transaction Amount</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

after you change using jquery `display:block` where you want like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#display").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: When i am using inline css that time working fine but when i am using jquery css that time not working

Comment: you can use  $(document).load(function() {
      $("#display").css("display", "none");
   });

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should change logic and let the div always hidden and change to display when is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
$(document).load(function () {
    $("#display").css("display", "none");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#display").css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your div to be hidden when the page loads or is fully loaded, you can assign a CSS class with this property to the div:

```css
display: none
```

This way the div will be hidden when the page loads. You can change the display property with jQuery or JS later on with events

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
#display { diaplay:none; } /* but this in your css file*/


<div id="display">
        <div class="w-section">
            <label style="margin-left: 285px;">Coupon Name</label>
        </div>      
        <div class="w-section" >
            <label style="margin-left: 285px;">Transaction Amount</label>
        </div>
</div>

//but this in script tag in the bottom of your page
    $(function() {
           $("#display").css("display", "block");
       });
```